# Django Image Upload Form not valid

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

For some reason in django the form that I am trying to use is not considered valid. This code is taken almost directly from a site that claims that it works but is still not functional.
my code is as follows.

VIEWS

```
def display_update_image(request, pk):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        display = Display.objects.get(pk = pk)
        display.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
        display.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('displays'))
else :
    form = ImageForm()
return render(request, 'catalog/update_display_image.html', {'form': form})
```

TEMPLATE (template name is update_display_image.html)

```
<form method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<p>
    <input id = "id" type = "file" class = "" name = "image">
</p>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
```

MODELS

```
class Display(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50,)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images')
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

edit: forget to post Forms code sorry

```
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

further edit: changing my forms class to this

```
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Display
        fields = ('image',)
```

Allows the form to be read as valid for some reason though I don't understand why. Unfortunately that causes my views method to be unable to function properly as it can no longer read

```
display.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
```

Comment: can you post de code of the `ImageForm`?

Comment: the form class with the model should be `class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you form class is a modelform: `class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):` you can pass the instance to the form and save it.

```
def display_update_image(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        display = Display.objects.get(pk = pk)
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=display)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('displays'))
    else :
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'catalog/update_display_image.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

In `forms.py` check that you have a Django Form like this one:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Display
        fields = ['image',]
```

In `template` add `{{ form }}` instead of manually using `input`, like this one:

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart-formdata>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type='submit' value='Update Image'>
```

Comment: Ahh sorry I forgot to mentioned I did have a similar form, Once I update the those two files to be the same as you mentioned it does read the form as being valid. Unfortunately it doesn't recognize
form.cleaned_data['image'] from my views once I hit submit.

Comment: @user8265778 can you paste the error that you are getting?

Comment: KeyError at /catalog/display/97ee7328-ccda-447d-b454-2ac53b0bf831/update-image/
the exception location is the line I mentioned

Comment: Correct indentation in `ImageForm(forms.ModelForm)`